# Redoing surface without disturbing neighboring surfaces?

Tags: modeling

Newbie here. I modeled the front panels of a car using a low-poly + subsurf modifier approach. I realized I need to modify the surface forward of the fender, but doing so distorts the fender and surrounding surfaces.

I won't ask if I'm doing it right, so I won't bother you with how I'm doing it now. I just want to know:

When you need to modify a surface with lots of features and details that you can't afford to disturb, do you normally edit the original surface, or do you delete the offending faces to start over with brand new geometry?

Comment: Screenshots are always helpful when it comes to giving specific advice :)

Comment: A million times what stphnl329 said; Even if you reduce the scope of the question, screenshots help immensely with context.

Comment: Not only do I save my project in increments often I will also save duplicates of meshes as I work within my projects in case I need to revisit older versions of my creations. Then you can delete away and continue to work with plenty of back versions to return to if needed. You will ultimately develop your own workflow...